# Is Boolean Algebra knowledge required in android dev.?

Tags: android

I stumbled across a piece of code that made me somewhat confused ,, when I researched I saw some bitmasking and bit-wise operations going on .. so do I need to know that stuff? cause I thought the device's orientation would be a value defined somewhere in the sdk not developer defined as below.

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        phoneDevice = false;
    }
```

Also why are there many constants for supposedly the same thing A.K.A

Orientation Costants defined in *Configuration* vs those defined in *ActivityInfo* ?

Comment: Bitmasking and bit-wise operations are not boolean algebra. Are you asking about binary operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not required, and moreover, the devices orientation is something that is within the SDK that you can check:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // In landscape
} else {
    // In portrait
}
```

If however, you're talking about boolean logic, then yes, it's very much needed in all parts of software development.